# PHP long if statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this if statment here and its not working

```
if(
    ($division->id == 1 || $division->id == 2) && 
    in_array('member1', $memberships) || 
    in_array('member2', $memberships) ||
    in_array('member3', $memberships) ||
    in_array('member4', $memberships) || 
    ($division->id != 1 || $division->id != 2) 
    && in_array('member5', $memberships))
    {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is say if $division is 1 or 2 and if member1, member2, member3, member4 are in the array $memberships return false, if $division is not 1 or 2 and member5 is in the array return false, everything else return true.

This is not working because member5 is in the array and $division is 1, which should return true, but it returns false.

PS - member1-5 are just names I am using for here as they actually are personal information in my array.

What Am i doing wrong?

Comment: There's no need to do all that in one single if statement - break it down into the separate parts.

Comment: You need _at least_ a `()` group around the `member1-member4` `in_array()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this as a series of different 'if' statements, to avoid you going around the bend trying to work it out.

I've created this piece of code according to your statement...

> What I am trying to do is say if $division is 1 or 2 and if member1,
>   member2, member3, member4 are in the array $memberships return false,
>   if $division is not 1 or 2 and member5 is in the array return false,
>   everything else return true.

I think I've got the logic right, I'm about to double check it:

```
if ($division->id == 1 || $division->id == 2)
{
    if (in_array("member_2", $memberships) || in_array("member_3", $memberships) || in_array('member_3', $memberships) || in_array('member_4', $memberships))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
else
{
    if (in_array("member_5", $memberships))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the logical groupings, 1 per line. Use parenthesis to adjust how php evaluates it if this isnt what you want.

```
   ($division->id == 1 || $division->id == 2) && in_array('member1', $memberships)
|| in_array('member2', $memberships) 
|| in_array('member3', $memberships) 
|| in_array('member4', $memberships) 
|| ($division->id != 1 || $division->id != 2) && in_array('member5', $memberships))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(
(($division->id == 1 || $division->id == 2) && 
(in_array('member1', $memberships) || 
in_array('member2', $memberships) ||
in_array('member3', $memberships) ||
in_array('member4', $memberships))) || 
(($division->id != 1 || $division->id != 2) 
&& in_array('member5', $memberships)))
{
    return FALSE;
} else {
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less lines of code does not always mean it's better, break it down and make it readable, for example:

```
$output = true;

if($division->id == 1 || $division->id == 2)
{
    if(in_array("member_2", $memberships) || in_array("member_3", $memberships) || in_array('member_4', $memberships))
    {
        $output = false;
    }
}
else
{
    if (in_array("member_5", $memberships))
    {
        $output = false;
    }
}

return $output;
```